# New Xcode 7.3 error - Ambiguous us of 'view'

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7.3

The following code worked properly prior to upgrading to Xcode 7.3;

func myMethod() {

```
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CreateButtonObject.notifyButtonAction(_:)))
            let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CreateButtonObject.notifyButtonAction(_:)))
            tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
```

}

```
@IBAction @objc func notifyButtonAction (sender: AnyObject) {

    let userInfo:Dictionary<String,AnyObject!>
    print("Sender from tap or longpress: \(sender)")
    **let button = sender.view as! UIButton**
    let soundName = button.currentTitle!

    userInfo = ["sender" : sender]

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(sleepEZButtonActionNotificationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)

    DDLogDebug("CreateButtonObject.notifyButtonAction: Notificaiton! ButtonViewController")
    DDLogDebug("CreateButtonObject.notifyButtonAction: Posted Notification sleepEZButtonActionNotificationKey to initiate buttonAction")
    DDLogDebug("CreateButtonObject.notifyButtonAction: Button Name: \(soundName)")
    DDLogDebug("")
}
```

But now when I do this in Xcode 7.3 I get the following error on the line with sender.view ;
Ambiguous use of 'view'

followed by a compiler error.

Anyone know what's going on here and how to fix.  Can't figure this out.  Basically I need to get the UIButton attributes out of the UITapGesureRecognizer object that is created and then activated on a button press.  Stuck.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: By the way, the phrase `@IBAction @objc` is redundant. `@IBAction` implies `@objc`.

Comment: Prior to the 7.3 upgrade I only used "@IBAction" but after recieved errors when attempting to compile. Error indicated I needed to add "@objc" so I did. No more errors. Error stems from the change to use #selector deprecating the previous syntax and use of Selector.

Answer (score 3):

In the declaration `func notifyButtonAction (sender: AnyObject)`, you have typed `sender` as AnyObject. But an AnyObject doesn't have a `view`. So in your line `sender.view as! UIButton`, the phrase `sender.view` is illegal.

Type `sender` as a UIGestureRecognizer if that's what it is: `func notifyButtonAction (sender: UIGestureRecognizer)`. A gesture recognizer does have a `view`, so all will be well.